# Implementing One-Month License for React Project: Auto-Deactivation Feature

Tags: reactjs, node.js, project

I have created a project in React and Node. I have given this project and database to the client for 1 month so how can I close the project after one month? In the project, no API of our server is called! So tell me if there is any solution.

searching in google but not find any way

Comment: Have a function that checks todays date against a value, but if you have already given them the project how will you edit it?

Comment: Can you deploy the nodeJS project to a server, then simply turn the server off after one month